# Difference between *3 in String to make Each Characters Triple

Tags: python

I have a code that answer the question, the code is like this:

```
def three_words(text):
    result = ''
    for letter in text:
        result += letter*3

    return print(result)
```

The function is returning three characters of each letter, example Ab will return `AAAbbb`

My question is why it is not returning `AbAbAb`?, like when I did with the code below:

```
str = 'Ab'*3

print(str)
```

I just confused, someone please help me.

Comment: What *exactly* don't you understand? Do you know how a `for` loop works? Did you try to run this code by hand step by step?

Answer (score 0):

basically when you loop through a string you get each seperate character per loop:

```
test = '123'

for c in test:
    print(c)
```

output:

```
'1'
'2'
'3'
```